# Strange behavior with TypeScript ambient declarations in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

I have always been using a file `interfaces.d.ts` to add custom type helpers into it and suddenly in a new project I am getting this weird stuff.

As soon as I close the file, the typings get lost. When I reopen it, the typings are back.
[image]

Moreover, when I move the file from `src/interfaces.d.ts` to `interfaces.d.ts`, the file gets automatically added to `tsconfig.json` `include` field. However, it does not work when it is added there, removing it makes the typings available, but the above issue takes place later.

[image]

What is going on and how can I fix that?
Why does it work in my other projects?

The other project's `tsconfig.json` with typings located at `src/interfaces.d.ts`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: I think it is preferable if you used `src/**/*.ts` so that all TS files are picked up, not just TS files directly in `src`. Also should try the `types` and `typeRoots` compiler options.

Comment: @kellys Yeah, `**/*.ts` is the only difference between the two configs and changing this actually fixes the type discoverability ‍♂️. However, I still don't understand why this fixed it, since the file was still referenced before, and what is going on in general with the above.